# Is "remover of obstacles" one or more names in the Vishnu Sahasra Nama?

Tags: vishnu-sahasranama

I looked up all the names starting in V (for vighna) and couldn't find one starting with Vighna.

Comment: It's not a name, but it's in the dhyanam (_sarva vignoba shantayet_)